# Centering elements in kivy: using root vs self.parent

Tags: python, kivy

I'm reading the kivy documentations. In it, there's an example on how to make [your own pong game](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/tutorials/pong.html#).

In general, the tutorial is very clear. However, at some point there was something subtle I wasn't sure about.

They make a ball in the `.kv` file:

```
<PongBall>:
    size: 50,50
    canvas:
        Ellipse:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
```

Then, they add an instance of a `PongBall` to a previously defined `PongGame` class:

```
<PongGame>:
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            pos:self.center_x - 5 , 0
            size : 10, self.height
    Label:
        font_size : 70
        center_x : root.width / 4
        top : root.top - 50
        text : "0"
    Label:
        font_size : 70
        center_x : root.width / 4 * 3
        top : root.top - 50
        text: "0"
    PongBall:
        center: self.parent.center
```

In the `PongGame` labels they added, the set the location using `root`, which references the `PongGame`
For the `PongBall` they set the location using `self.parent.center`, where `self.parent` appears to reference the `PongGame`. I am assuming there is a reason they used:

```
<PongBall>:
    PongBall:
        center: self.parent.center
```

instead of

```
<PongBall>:
    PongBall:
        center: root.center
```

Why did they not use `root.center` as they did for the labels? Is there a reason for picking one over the other? Is there a difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They do this, because the ball should be relative to the position of the game widget. The labels on the other hand are "dead". They just have to "exist" at the point they got in the beginning of the game, but the ball has to "live"